# patch function with same name as module python django mock

Tags: python, django, mocking, patch

```
|-- my_module
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- function.py
`-- test.py
```

in function.py:

```
import other_function

def function():
    doStuff()
    other_function()
    return
```

in __init__.py

```
from .function import function
```

in my test.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from mock import patch
from my_module import function

class Test(TestCase):

    @patch('my_module.function.other_function')
    def function_test(self, mock_other_function):
         function()
```

When I run this I got a 
AttributeError:

> <@task: my_module.function.function of project:0x7fed6b4fc198> does not have
>   the attribute 'other_function'

Which means that I am trying to patch the function "function" instead of the module "function". I don't know how to make it understand that I want to patch the module.

I would also like to avoid renaming my module or function.

Any ideas?

[Edit]
You can find an example at https://github.com/vthorey/example_mock
run

```
python manage.py test
```

Comment: Have you got the solution for this ?

Comment: @HaykDavtyan Nope. You can upvote the question if you want to increase visibility ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7 years later I faced the same issue and found a thread that proposes a solution here:

[How to mock a function called in a function inside a module with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52324568/how-to-mock-a-function-called-in-a-function-inside-a-module-with-the-same-name)

Answer (score 3):

You could make the module available under a different name in `__init__.py`:

```
from . import function as function_module
from .function import function
```

Then you can do the following in `test.py`:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from mock import patch
from my_module import function

class Test(TestCase):

    @patch('my_module.function_module.other_function')
    def function_test(self, mock_other_function):
         function()
```

I do not think this is a particularly elegant solution - the code is not very clear to a casual reader.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I was using a string. I edited the question!

Comment: Can you provide an example that actually runs and hits the error? I used the `requests` package as `other_function` and my code ran fine

Comment: https://github.com/vthorey/example_mock you can run python manage.py test to get the error

Comment: @v.thorey i'm kinda stuck in a similar situation. I dont have anything inside my __init__.py file. Does adding ->  "from . import function as function_module" fix the issue ? or is there an alternate work around ?